# HTML Class reference

Tags: html, css

I've a little problem with this code.
My css class has the name:

```
section.border button
```

From what I would like to create **a href** with the look of < button >

```
<a data-scroll href="#link" class="section border button">Go to</a>
```

This method unfortunately isn't working.

```
<section class="border">
    <button>Click</button> <- it's OK
<a data-scroll href="#test" class="section border button">Go to Google</a> <- NOPE
</section>
```

## CSS

```
section.border button {
  color: #f6f6f6;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border: solid 2px #f6f6f6;
  padding:10px 40px 10px 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow;
  transition-property: box-shadow;
  -webkit-transition-property: background-color;
  transition-property: background-color;

    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-family: "Lato";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: box-shadow:  0 0 12px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: box-shadow:  0 0 12px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow:  0 0 12px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
/* Hack to improve aliasing on mobile/tablet devices */
}
section.border button:hover,
section.border button.hover,section.border button:active,
section.border button.active  {
  border-color: white;
  background-color: rgba(187,187,187, 0.3);
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow:  0 0 12px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Comment: @Berdesdan check out now. I've updated the post.

Comment: `<section class="border"><button>this is the area being targeted</button></section>` that CSS selector isn't targeting an anchor tag at all.

Comment: @Scott Yes, you have right. I get it now

Comment: @test :) ... was working on an assumed answer.  Didn't read your updated post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a custom css name, and add it to every items you want to show as a button.

```
section.border button, .myButton { ... }
```

```
<section class="border">
    <button>Click</button>
    <a class="myButton">Go to Google</a>
</section>
<a class="myButton">Go to Bing</a>
```

Comment: Oh god, It was such a simply solution. I don't why I didn't came up with an idea. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Go to Google 
does't match any of those css rules.

The css rule is for a button inside a section that has a `border` class

```
<section class="border">
   <button >Go to Google</button>
</section>
```